# Tkinter Integral Symbol

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to be able to pack an integral symbol into a label like this:

```
result = 5
Label(root,text='INTEGRAL x: ' + result).pack()
```

Is there a way to get that squiggly S in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral symbol is U+222B in Unicode. I'm leaving in around 30 seconds (or so I was told two minutes ago), so I can't test it right now, but it should display just fine.

Cheers.